# Hyperledger Composer Query Language LIKE operator

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

just wanted to know if there someone in here that knows how to create query in hyperledger composer query language that uses wildcard filtering. Just the same with LIKE operator in SQL. I tried to use the CONTAINS operator but it seems like it is not working properly to me. Hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the details of what you are trying, and the results you are seeing?

Comment: Basically, I have a website that can search for a record and I want to get the result/s using only the specified search term. For example I type 'a', all records that has 'a' in their first name for example will be returned.